# How can I secure a Spyne web service with SSL?

Tags: ssl, spyne

I'm trying to get a SOAP web service set up with Spyne.  So far, so good.  I have a web service,but not I need to secure the data in-flight with SSL.  Is there a way to attach a certificate to the Spyne app so my connection is encrypted?
Thank you!

I've looked at the help guides on Spyne.io and have not found the info I need about SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use either a reverse proxy setup (like nginx) that will terminate the SSL connection outside of the Python process (recommended) or you have to use OpenSSL (or similar) bindings to create an SSL socket for yourself.

You can use twisted's ssl capabilities via the WsgiApplication. Have a look: https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-17.9.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html

Comment: I used Nginx. Works great.  Thank you.